# Is there a method to add ros path in python scripts?

Tags: ros, python

Well, I'm tring to start a launch file in python like this example:

```
import roslaunch
import rospy

rospy.init_node('en_Mapping', anonymous=True)
uuid = roslaunch.rlutil.get_or_generate_uuid(None, False)
roslaunch.configure_logging(uuid)
launch = roslaunch.parent.ROSLaunchParent(uuid, ["/home/haier/catkin_ws/src/testapi/launch/test_node.launch"])
launch.start()
rospy.loginfo("started")

rospy.sleep(3)
# 3 seconds later
launch.shutdown()
```

but if execute the python directly it will tell that some pkg or node not found in ros path, so we have to source devel/setup.bash in our workspace dir at the beginning. But if I have two workspace ,and there is two different node with the same name, it is likely not able to source both two workspace. Is there any method to add ros path in python scritpts so that I could control the find_pkg path in my code block?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! launch file should better be executed from .launch file and then those file should execute nodes that could be written in Python. But speaking of your issue, you may need to set `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and others as mentioned [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables). However, I never recommend such practices.

Comment: `But if I have two workspace ,and there is two different node with the same name, it is likely not able to source both two workspace` I think this is by design. What are you trying to do that you find yourself trying to run two nodes in two different workspaces that have the same name?

Comment: Thanks, the truth is that there are two workspace with different functions , so  I want to keep them isolated although they may use the same child pkg. And also I want to manage the function and node start/close in python scripts. Now I've merged them into one workspace. The problem remains that I don't want to source, I'll try to change the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in scripts to solve it.